# Merge tables and keeping all distinct ID values

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables to merge and these tables may have different ID values.

For example:

Table 1:

```
ID Year Month Size1
A  2015   4    10
B  2015   5    20
```

Table 2:

```
ID Year Month Size2
A  2015   4    20
C  2015   5    40
```

Table 3:

```
ID Year Month Size3
D  2015   6    50
E  2015   7    50
```

I want the merged table to look like this:

```
ID Year Month Size1 Size2 Size3
A  2015   4     10    20   NULL
B  2015   5     20   NULL  NULL
C  2015   5    NULL   40   NULL
D  2015   6    NULL  NULL  50
E  2015   7    NULL  NULL  50
```

I want the output ID column to include all distinct IDs from all the tables.
My guess is that this can be somehow achieved by using Full Outer Join On ID, but I wasn't quite able to produce the desired output format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another possible query that would give the result you show:

```
SELECT t.id, t.year, t.month, 
  SUM(size1) AS size1, SUM(size2) AS size2, SUM(size3) AS size3 
FROM (
  SELECT id, year, month, size1, NULL AS size2, NULL AS size3 FROM t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, year, month, NULL, size2, NULL FROM t2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, year, month, NULL, NULL, size3 FROM t3
) AS t
GROUP BY t.id, t.year, t.month;
```

Comment: Bill, your approach works with minor changes:

SELECT t.id, t.year, t.month, 
  SUM(t.size1) AS size1, SUM(t.size2) AS size2, SUM(t.size3) AS size3 

FROM (
  SELECT id, year, month, size1, NULL AS size2, NULL AS size3 FROM t1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, year, month, NULL AS size1, size2, NULL As size3 FROM t2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, year, month, NULL AS size1, NULL AS size2, size3 FROM t3
) AS t

GROUP BY t.id, t.year, t.month;

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, t1.year, t1.month, t1.size1, t2.size2, t3.size3 
from table1 as t1
left outer join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.year = t2.year and t1.month = t2.month
left outer join table3 as t3 on t1.id = t3.id and t1.year = t3.year and t1.month = t3.month
union
select t3.id, t3.year, t3.month, t1.size1, t2.size2, t3.size3 
from table3 as t3
left outer join table1 as t1 on t3.id = t1.id and t3.year = t1.year and t3.month = t1.month
left outer join table2 as t2 on t3.id = t2.id and t3.year = t2.year and t3.month = t2.month
```